# java transfer data from superclass to child

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

I would like to transfer data from a superclass (a database entity) to a child that extend the superclass adding some other field.

It exist a simple mode to transfer the data of the superclass into the  (new) child?

Thank you

Comment: A super-class should have no knowledge or dependencies on its children. You've got your design all wrong.

Comment: What do you mean, "transfer data?"  That makes no sense.  Please show an example of what you are referring to.

Comment: Can't you do `super.getMyInterestingValue()`? I mean, the parent already has that data, right?

Comment: Child classes already inherit non-private superclass fields/methods. Is that what you meant with data transfer? If you want to get a uninherited value from the superclass you will have to use a method like Fjotten suggested.

Answer (score -1):

A super class knows nothing about the child class. Although this is generally considered a bad practice, you could just pass-in external data into the child class. Something like this:

```
child.setChildData(parent.getParentData);
```